# How I can install an external module in my Angular project?

Tags: angular, installation, module

I try to learn Angular with this tuto : https://angular.io/tutorial.

At the part 6, I need install a module "In-memory Web API" (https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api)

[What it's writte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g7jo.png)

But, I don't have steps to install it.

Somebody can explain me please ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a new angular package, you need to add the package name to the `package.json` file in your project, under the `dependencies` or `devDependencies`

- `Dependencies` are packages that are essential to running your
  application.
- `DevDependencies` are packages that are necessary to develop
  applications (i.e for testing).

add the name of the package and the version you want:

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.11.0"
```

once you update the file, you should run the `npm install` to install the latest added package.

a shorter way would also be to run the following npm commend, that will both install the package and add it to the package.json dependencies for you:

```
npm i angular-in-memory-web-api --save
```

[read more on npm packages](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages)